Could phytoplankton in the Poles have a baseline photosynthesis activity during polar nights using auroras as a light source?
Polar nights refer to the phenomenon where there are extended periods of darkness where the Sun hardly arises from the horizon in the polar winter.
However, there are other dim light dources like auroras. Could photosynthetic microorganisms (such as phytoplankton) use this as a source for a very basic photosynthetic activity and primary production of sugars?
Also in this article (https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.abc2678) the authors indicate that microalgae could grow in extremely low light conditions during the Arctic polar night.
My question is: Can these organisms use very dim light sources like aurora borealis to produce a very basic photosynthetic activity and produce sugars or fats to survive?
Related: https://www.sciencenews.org/article/algae-light-phytoplankton-grow-dark-arctic-winter-ice

This question is similar to: Could plants do photosynthesis at moonlight?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
